# Transfer contacts / emails from Windows Live mail to Gmail?

Tags: gmail, google-contacts, outlook.com, migrate-data

Does anybody know how I can transfer all my email messages, contacts and calendar entries from Live Mail (formerly Hotmail) to Gmail?

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the contacts - you should export all your contacts to a .csv file. Under correction,  you should be able to do this by going to options, customize contacts and then export contacts.

Then in Gmail you should go to contacts and "import" contacts. I am not entirely sure about the calender entries, but I've successfully migrated contacts in the past from Apple Mail, Outlook, Outlook for Mac and incredimail - all to Gmail (and by .csv format)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily import it to gmail

1. Copy All the messages to your windows mail inbox
2. Goto Settings tab of your gmail account
3. Goto Accounts and import tab
4. Click Import mails and contacts
5. Type your Windows Live Hotmail email address under What account which you wish to import
6. Make sure Import contacts and Import mail are checked.
7. Click on Start Import

This will Import all of your email and contacts

Answer (score 0):

1. Log in to https://people.live.com/ with your "Windows Live Mail" account.
2. Click on Manage(Placed in Header)
3. Click on Export to Outlook.com and other services.
4. Save the generated .csv file on your computer.
5. Log in to your Gmail account.
6. Click on Gmail at the top-left corner of your Gmail page, then choose Contacts.
7. Click the More button above the contacts list and select Import....
8. Click the Choose File button.
9. Select the .csv file to upload and click the Import button.