# Transfering Outlook to Google Calendar and then using just Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar, outlook

I want to convert my Outlook Calendar into the Google Calendar and then only use the Google Calendar.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Product recommendations are generally disallowed here. Please read our [help].

Comment: @Krampus: I don't believe a 3rd party tool is required here so I edited the question to make it sound less like it was asking for a recommendation.

Comment: For the Contacts part > http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/49680/transfer-contacts-emails-from-windows-live-mail-to-gmail/49681#49681

Answer (score 3):

You can simply export/Save-as the calendar from MS Outlook and import it into Google calendar. Note, however, that there does appear to be a restriction with Outlook's repeating events.

From Google's import dialog: "Google Calendar can import event information in ical or CSV (MS Outlook)"

> 1. Open Outlook
> 2. Click Calendar
> 3. Right click on the calendar you need to export and choose Save as
> 4. Select type iCalendar format
> 5. Click on More Options and select Date Range -> Whole calendar, Detail -> Full details
> 6. Click OK and then Save
> 7. In Google Calendar, click the down-arrow next to Other calendars
> 8. Select Import calendar
> 9. Click Choose file and find the file that contains your events, then click Open
> 10. Select the Google Calendar where you'd like to import events, then click Import

Source: [Import events from other applications](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/83126?hl=en-GB&rd=1)